# ASP.Net MVC, Ninject IOC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, inversion-of-control

I'm using Ninject to do some dependancy injection. (Mainly for the DAL), my project consists of 3 aspects and are as follows,

1. Project.Lib (Everything database,
   services and anythign else that is
   logic)
2. Project.Admin (Administration)
3. Project.Web (Front end what the user
   see's)

Now, each of my controllers within my projects inherit from a BaseController

```
 public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected BaseController(ISession session)
        {
            _Session = session;
        }

        public ISession _Session { get; private set; }
    }
```

And then and example controller might be like so,

```
 public class ImageController : BaseController
    {
        private MediaService _mediaService;

        public ImageController(ISession session) : base(session)
        {
            _mediaService = new MediaService(session);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult List()
        {   
            var RetVal = _mediaService.GetAllImages();
            return View(RetVal);
        }
}
```

As you can see the "Session" is passed from the controller to the service layer. I'm curious as to if this is good practie? ANy negitives to what we are doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid referencing ISession through your controller. A better solution would be to use Ninject to inject your services into your controllers. In this instance you'll need to create an abstraction for your `MediaService` class e.g.:

```
public interface IMediaService 
{
    SomeCollection GetAllImages();
    // ...
}
```

You'd then use Ninject to supply an implementation of the above interface to your controller:

```
public class ImageController : BaseController
{
    private IMediaService _mediaService;

    public ImageController(IMediaService mediaService)
    {
        _mediaService = mediaService
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult List()
    {   
        var RetVal = _mediaService.GetAllImages();
        return View(RetVal);
    }
```

}

Comment: But there are almost 12 service classes? We couldnt inject them all into every controller?

Comment: Technically there's no reason why you couldn't, and it would remove the dependencies between your controllers and services making things easier to unit test. Having said that, if you have a controller with that many dependencies it might be a sign that your application design isn't scaling well or you need to move some responsibility into another controller.

Comment: each controller generally only uses 1 (in some cases 2) services. Maybe I mis-interpreted what you actually meant?